# Lanzar script desde botón html-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente botón de una plantilla de bootstrap.

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">texto_boton &raquo;</a></p>
```

Como puedo hacer para que onclick me lance un script que se encuentra en la carpeta js

Comment: podrías especificar que necesitar lanzar precisamente?  una función ? o algo más?, en los comentarios dices que un script? porque necesitas cargar el script al click? y no declararlo en el html.

Comment: Necesito un botón que cargue un archivo de texto y otro botón que lo lea con expresines regulares. Las expresiones regulares ya están echas y son muchas funciones, una para cada dato que quiero extraer del archivo .txt Probablmente no lo esté orientando bien

Comment: Lo de las expresiones regulares puedes validarlas en la función.Quizas deberías hacer nuevamente la pregunta incluyendo estas nuevas observaciones.

Comment: Creo que es lo que voy a hacer. Replantear de nuevo el problema y la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Quieres que se ejecute el script al presionar el botón o que se cargue con la página para que cuando se presione el botón se pueda llamar a una de las funciones del script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero que nada tenes que tener linkeado el script al html..

Un simple ejemplo seria:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="Link al archivo"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si ya lo tenes linkeado agregas un:

```
onClick="nombreDeLaFuncion();"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href='javascript:;' onclick="nombreDeLaFuncion();" role="button">
  texto_boton &raquo;
</a>
```

De esta forma estarías ejecutando una función javascript cunado se hace un click en ese link desde un archivo externo.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que se cargue un fichero cada vez que se pulsa un enlace, podrías hacerlo así:

```
<p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id="boton">texto_boton &raquo;</a>
</p>

<script>
// seleccionamos el enlace 
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

// cuando se pulsa en el enlace
boton.onclick = function(e) {
    // evitamos la acción por defecto
    e.preventDefault();
    // creamos una etiqueta script
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    // indicamos en el atributo src el fichero que quieres cargar
    s.src = "ruta/a/tu/codigo.js";
    // lo añadimos al documento (y se ejecuta automaticamente)
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(s);
    // borra el script del documento (para evitar basura si se ejecuta multiples veces)
    s.remove();
}
</script>
```

---

Pero por lo que leo en los comentarios, me parece que lo que quieres es que cada vez que se carga un fichero de texto se ejecute un script. Para ello quizás te interesa otra cosa:

- Envuelve todo el código dentro de una función (incluso si son funciones, en JavaScript puedes tener funciones dentro de funciones).
- Al principio de la función creada asigna los valores adecuados.
- Cuando se lea el fichero, llama a la nueva función con los parámetros necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

probaste con

```
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" onclick="miFuncion()">texto_boton &raquo;</a></p>
```

Comment: Y se puede cargar un script en lugar de una función ? Tengo un .js con treinta funciones

Comment: Para eso lo llamas asi: <script Language=Javascript src="miarchivo.js"></script >

Comment: Esto no contesta la pregunta, lo que se necesita (aparentemente) es que se ejecute un script que está en un archivo externo al hacer clic en el botón (`a` disfrazado de botón)

Comment: No tengo claro como lo quiero hacer.
Cuando cargo el jscript las variables quedan como undefined hasta que le asigno a una de las variables el texto contenido en el archivo que leo del equipo local.
No se como gestiono ese "undefined" hasta que cargue el .txt
Creo que no manejo los tiempos de ejecución.
O lo llevó todo mezclado.

Comment: He aprendido (algo) con Python. Esto es otro mundo.
Resulta que me hace falta un evento para una acción.
Eso es lo que me está confundiendo.
Tendré que redefinir todas mis funciones.
Menos funciones y con más bloques.
Pero no puedo hacer un return múltiple, por esa razón he creado una función por cada dato extraído de un texto.
Ahora no tengo treinta botones para hacer treinta operaciones.
Tengo que rediseñarlo todo.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas es:

```
<script Language=Javascript src="miarchivocon30funciones.js"></script >

function mifuncion() {

    //LLamar aquí las funciones de miarchivocon30funciones.js   
    funcion1();
   funcion2();


}

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href='javascript:;' onclick='mifuncion();return false;'role="button">texto_boton &raquo;</a>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Esto no contesta la pregunta, lo que se necesita (aparentemente) es que se ejecute un script que está en un archivo externo al hacer clic en el botón (`a` disfrazado de botón)

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Quiere decir que quieres ejecutar todo el script? o una función en particular?